# how are negative numbers stored within the EVM stack?

Tags: evm, bytecode, opcode

for example, I have these opcodes:

```
PUSH60
PUSH40
SUB
```

for sub operations, I believe that the second stack item is subtracted from the first stack item (60 - 40) which would equal to -20 being the new first stack item. I know this would be stored as hexadecimal, but does the stack store negative numbers? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, sorry was quite simple, it would be stored as uint, as -20 modular (%) 2^256